# covering chess board with 3*1 dominoes

Tags: tiling

Why is it not possible to cover the chess board with 3X1 dominoes if one of the corner squares is missing (e.g. the top right square)?

Comment: Try colouring the board, instead of two colours, with three colours $abcabcab$

Answer (score 1):

Color the board in vertical stripes of red, blue, and yellow squares.  There are three full columns of red squares, so $24$.  There are $23$ blue squares, because one is removed.  There are $16$ yellow squares.  Each tromino covers either three squares or one of each.  The quantity $red + yellow -2blue \bmod 3$ doesn't change as we place trominos, but it starts out $2$ and ends $0$.